# Amping indoor and outdoor speakers

Tags: mixer

I'm helping a friend with their resturant.

They have indoor and outdoor passive speakers connected to a single amp.  How can I go about making the outside louder with out making the inside loud.

Do I need to seperate amps or do I need some kind of powered mixer?

Comment: Really you probably need a good vendor. But in the meantime it's most likely something like a 70V system that would not work with most powered mixers. Better to just get a separate compatible amp for the outside speakers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good and safe way to do what you're asking without 2 amps or a two channel amp which might be already there. That would also probably be the cheapest solution to what you're asking about. A powered mixer would be a possible solution if it had more than a mono powered output, which most do. You could use the "left" for outdoor and the "right" for indoor as an example.

The best solution would involve a lot more work and money. Installing a "Constant Voltage System" usually a 70v system in the US, but it could be a 25v or 100v too. they have "zones" where you can change the volume per zone. That is something you really want a professional setting up.